# Spark k8s driver fails without any specific error

Tags: scala, docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-streaming

I'm trying to run a spark application on k8s and it fails immediately after container creation. No specific error. I see only error code 101

```
Container name: spark-kubernetes-driver
Container image: image URL
Container state: Terminated
Exit code: 101



Driver logs
    + CMD=("$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit" --conf "spark.driver.bindAddress=$SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS" --deploy-mode client "$@")
    + exec /usr/bin/tini -s -- /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.driver.bindAddress=10.1.0.10 --deploy-mode client --properties-file /opt/spark/conf/spark.properties --class $className spark-internal args
```

Spark submit command

```
`bin/spark-submit  --class $className 
--master k8s://https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443 
--deploy-mode cluster 
--name app-job 
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthToken=$(kubectl get secret $(kubectl describe serviceaccount spark-sa --namespace=pipelines | grep Token | awk '{print $2}') -o jsonpath="{.data.token}" | base64 --decode) 
--conf spark.kubernetes.docker.image.pullPolicy=Always 
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark-sa 
--conf spark.executor.instances=2
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=pipelines 
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.container.image=$imageURL 
--conf spark.network.timeout=500 
--conf spark.metrics.namespace=app-job 
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.container.image=$imageURL $JARURL 10000`
```

Comment: Did you modify the spark submit command in order to hide the value of certain parameters? Because if not, spark-submit cannot work without the main class parameter (aka --class)

Comment: @AndD yes, it's modified. I have the proper class name in place

Comment: Ok, I asked because if you check the SparkSubmit.scala code, exit code 101 is used exactly to signal the error that the main class was not found (or that for some reason, it failed to load). I don't know if it is used for other reasons as well tho, but an idea could be to double check if the main class is correct and such. You can see the code here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit.scala but it should have log something more before exiting so maybe it's not related.

Comment: I'm giving the Jar artifactoy URL , is there a way to check the jar is getting downloaded or not ?